# API to get a content type against URL

Tags: nodes, 9

I have a scenario where I need to perform some redirection of a not found url

```
http://localhost/drupal9/node/1/search
```

the word search is added though a plugin I am using and it is a front-end route not a backend so upon refreshing this url I get **Not Found** which totally makes sense what I need to do is remove the word search from the URL and redirect to,

```
http://localhost/drupal9/node/1/
```

as search is a common word and can be used in other content type I first need to check whether the URL is of my custom content type. let me show you a piece of implementation I already have.

```
function [module]_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type', [module]);
$nids = $query->execute();
if(array_search(2,$nids)){
echo "yes";
}
}
```

so over here what I am doing is grabbing all the nodes with my content type and grabbing the Nid from URI and matching them and this does work but there is another problem with this.
In the page properties we have an option of **ALias** so if the user uses a custom alias, then I dont get the **Nid** in the URI anymore so this logic breaks,

the question may seem a bit tricky but the requirement is simple.I am looking for a unified solution to parse the URL into some drupal API and simply getting back the content type name.The Url may contain a custom alias or a Nid

Comment: Why don't you make an actual API with routes or a views page instead of this? Like /api/search/node/%?

Comment: I am using the default behavior at the moment as this works didnt find the need to move to other solutions, the url at the moment is created by drupal i dont have any influence with that.

Comment: What default behavior?

Comment: http://localhost/drupal9/node/1/ these urls are generated by drupal so in my case i can have multple pages for my custom content type and these urls are generated for each one of them, so i dont think i need to change it

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. If you want a front end that queries a URL to search nodes, this is not how it is done.

Comment: Incoming URLs go through two steps, first path processing, second route matching. The first step has to produce a valid internal path matching a route. To achieve this goal you can register as many path processors as you want, core for example uses one to remove the language prefix and then applies the alias table, so that aliases don't need to include the prefix. You can do for the appendix the same.